# Change order status if new customer ship to different address in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, account

I would like to have woocommerce change the order status of an order when Ship to different address is used & the customer has not successfully ordered before. 
Woocommerce would need to distinguish between failed past orders as it is possible the customer may have tried before but failed which means they will have orders in the system but they will be failed, cancel or pending.

I have already created a new order status in the system called **"verify"**, I would now like to run a script when an order is placed with "ship to different address" option that will checks if the customer has placed an order before or not. if not it change the order status to **"verify"**.

The first thing I tried was giving the customer an alert with the code below if they have only one order that says Your order will not ship until verified. But it displays no matter how many orders you have.

What I have tried is setting this code in `functions.php` file:

```
function wc_get_customer_orders() {

// Get all customer orders
$customer_orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
) );

$customer = wp_get_current_user();

// Text for our message
$notice_text = sprintf( 'Hey %1$s &#x1f600; As this is your first order with us, we will need to verify some info before shipping.', $customer->display_name );

// Display our notice if the customer has no orders
if ( count( $customer_orders ) == 1 ) {
    wc_print_notice( $notice_text, 'notice' );
}
 }
 add_action( 'woocommerce_before_my_account', 'wc_get_customer_orders' );
```

What I am missing is a way to only trigger this alert if they have chosen ship to different address and its their first order.

Also the code to update status to verify would need to be triggered there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has necessarily to be done first on WooCommerce "**Order received**" page *(thankyou page)*.

If it is a new customer and if a difference is detected between billing and shipping details, it will change the order status and you will display a custom notice with a button linked to the customer my account page.

In the my account page it will display a similar notice that you can customize differently *(or instead you could insert a text in the content, with instructions)*.

I have made a separated function that will count customer's orders in both hooked functions.

*WooCommerce has a dedicated counting function `wc_get_customer_order_count()`, but it's not convenient in this case.*

The code:

```
// Counting customer non failed orders (light sql query)
function get_customer_orders_action( $user_id, $status = true ){
    global $wpdb;

    // if argument $status is set to "false" we check for status 'wc-verify' instead
    $status_arg = $status ? "NOT LIKE 'wc-failed'" : "LIKE 'wc-verify'";

    // The light SQL query that count valid orders (no failed orders in count)
    $result = $wpdb->get_col( "
        SELECT COUNT(p.ID) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type LIKE '%shop_order%' AND p.post_status $status_arg
        AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user' AND pm.meta_value = $user_id
    " );

    return reset($result);
}

// Conditionally Changing the order status and displaying a custom notice based on orders count
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'new_customer_shipping_verification', 15, 1 );
function new_customer_shipping_verification( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id); // Get the order OBJECT

    // CHECK 1 - Only if customer has only 1 Order (the current one)
    if( get_customer_orders_action( $order->get_user_id() ) != 1 )
        return; // we exit

    // Get some shipping and billing details to compare
    $b_firstname = $order->get_billing_first_name();
    $s_firstname = $order->get_shipping_first_name();
    $b_address1 = $order->get_billing_address_1();
    $s_address1 = $order->get_shipping_address_1();

    // CHECK 2 - Only if there is a difference beetween shipping and billing details
    if( $b_firstname == $s_firstname && $b_address1 == $s_address1 )
        return;// we exit

    ##  ---  ---  Now we can update status and display notice  ---  ---  ##

    // Change order status
    $order->update_status('verify');

    // The complete billing name
    $user_name = $order->get_billing_first_name().' ';
    $user_name .= $order->get_billing_last_name();

    // The text message
    $text = __('Hey %s %s As this is your first order with us, we will need to verify some info before shipping.');
    $message = sprintf( $text, $user_name, '&#x1f600;' );
    // The button and the link
    $link = esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) );
    $button = '<a href="'.$link.'" class="button" style=float:right;>'.__('Check your info').'</a>';

    // Display the custom notice
    wc_print_notice( $message.$button, 'notice' );
}

// Conditionally Displaying a custom notice in my account pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'my_account_shipping_verification', 2 );
function my_account_shipping_verification(){
    // Get the current user ID
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );

    // Only if customer has almost an Order with status like 'verify'
    if( get_customer_orders_action( $user_id, false ) == 0 )
        return; // we exit

        // The complete billing name
        $user_name = $user_data->first_name.' ';
        $user_name .= $user_data->last_name;

        // The text message (to be completed)
        $text = __('Hey %s %s As this is your first order with us, we will need to...');
        $message = sprintf( $text, $user_name, '&#x1f600;' );

        // Display the custom notice (or it can be a normal text)
        wc_print_notice( $message, 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works

Comment: Thank you Loic for your help.

When i tested this code, i received the following Fatal Error.

Fatal error: Call to a member function get_user_id() on boolean in /home/******/public_html/wp-content/themes/*******/functions.php on line 1422

Comment: @305David … I have updated the answer… It was a little mistake. Please try it again, it should work this time. Thanks

Comment: Thank You Loic, Dont know what this wordpress forum would be with out your support.

I can confirm this code works.

It checks orders from new customers which have chosen the ship to different address, then sets their status to verify.

I have manually added some css to the class "verify" which expands the width and height of the status button on the order admin orders screen and also gives it a red background so store admins can visually see it better that there is an order which needs verifying.

Thanks again.

Comment: @305David I have started like everybody… Helping others answering give more knowledge, improve skills and ability to explain or teach…
 Customizing the code for your needs is a very good practice… Thanks :)